# Numpy FFT fails on meshgrids?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, fft

I'm running into an odd problem using Numpy meshgrids with the FFT functions. Specifically, either the fft2 or the ifft2 function seems to fail when used on an array built using meshgrids.

```
x = np.arange(-4, 4, .08)
y = np.arange(-4, 4, .08)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
field = (X + i*Y)*np.exp(X**2 + Y**2)
```

As a check before I proceeded with my project, I did

```
fieldCheck1 = np.fft.fft2(field)
fieldCheck2 = np.fft.ifft2(fieldCheck1)
```

which should yield back my original array, but in fact eliminates the real part ( a plot of `abs(fieldCheck2)**2` is flat zero, where originally it was a  gaussian) and completely scrambles the phase information (a phase plot of `fieldCheck2` looks like static instead of a phase ramp)

I've checked the documentation, but I don't see anything in there that would explain this. Any insight into the source of the problem would be helpful.

Comment: Is `i` the imaginary unit in your environment somehow? It is `1.0j` in mine.

Comment: yes, I set it that way at the beginning of all my code. Old bad habits are easier to work around than change.

Comment: Bitwise-or (``^``) will fail when used between a float and an int. Are you trying to exponentiate (``**``)?

Comment: Drat, I know, and I have it correct in my actual code--mistyped for here. I've corrected it in the original post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem (after replacing `^` with `**` in your code) is that the contrast between your smallest and largest values is nearly 30 orders of magnitude:

```
>>> abs(field).max() / abs(field).min()
8.8904389513698014e+28
```

Floating point arithmetic only has finite precision, so identities that work for *real* numbers will not always work for *floating point* numbers. As a simple example:

```
>>> x = 1
>>> y = 1e30
>>> z = x + y

>>> x == z - y
False
```

The FFT is essentially a more complicated version of this: you're adding very small numbers to very big numbers, and when you subtract the very big numbers again you get zero rather than the small number you expect.

Comment: This was the problem exactly. I was able to adjust some coefficients (not shown in my simplified code in the question) to reduce range and now everything works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

To add to the problem described by @jakevdp, it looks like you go into this whole mess because your function (after replacing `^` with `**` in your code)

```
field = (X + 1.0j*Y)*np.exp(X**2 + Y**2)
```

which you describe as being a Gaussian is in fact not quite so, as illustrated in this graph:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import numpy as np
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.plot_surface(X,Y,np.abs(field));
```

[image]

To get an actual 2D Gaussian function, try:

```
x = np.arange(-4, 4, .08)
y = np.arange(-4, 4, .08)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
field = np.exp(-(X**2 + Y**2))  # notice "-" sign in the exponent
```

Which would then give you the graph:

[image]

And corresponding error `np.abs(fieldCheck2-field)` for the round trip transform as (which is more in line with the expected numerical precision):

[image]